# sql multiple self joins efficient

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like the one below.  I need to write a query to find all names that are present in all the sources. In the example below this is only "john" & "mark".

```
source  name
a       john
b       john
c       john
d       john
a       pat
b       pat
a       mark
b       mark
c       mark
d       mark
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow isn't a code writing service :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the ALL statement, you can get the results you are expecting. Like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM dummy WHERE Source >= ALL (SELECT DISTINCT source FROM dummy);
```

See it in action: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf1c7/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

One method uses counting:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having count(distinct source) = (select count(distinct t2.source) from t t2);
```